# Fuel UX data grid without Pagination

Tags: datagrid, fuelux

I am trying to use Fuel UX Datagrid in a Rails 3.2 app. My use case requires a grid with fixed header (which Fuel UX Datagrid already supports) and vertical and horizontal scrolling without pagination. I found examples with vertical scrolling plus pagination but no examples with horizontal scrolling with pagination turned off. Does Fuel UX support this? Can someone post any examples?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is no existing option for this but it should be possible to disable pagination by configuring your datasource to return all records and using CSS to hide the pagination controls.  The horizontal scrolling is likely more difficult, but in general the JavaScript tries to be general enough to allow you customize your markup and CSS.  Feel free to experiment and report any customization issues to https://github.com/ExactTarget/fuelux/issues